# useEffect returning context function with null value

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect, react-context

I am using a context configuration (not redux) that consists of three files. A state file, reducer file, and context file. It makes an axios call to my Atlas MongoDB collection. I have tested the API using Postman and the get request works as intended, returning a series of transaction data.

The getTransactions() function in the useEffect hook will only return the requested data once. If I make any modifications to the code and save or navigate to a different page and return, the transactions array of objects is now defined as null. My first instinct was that I had an asynchronous syntax error but my understanding of useEffect is that it mitigates async issues.

The function in question looks like this:

```
const initialState = {
    transactions: null,
    current: null,
    filtered: null,
    error: null
  };

  const getTransactions = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get("/api/transactions");

      dispatch({ type: GET_TRANSACTIONS, payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: TRANSACTION_ERROR, payload: err.response.msg });
    }
  };
```

The reducer handles the type dispatched by the state function inside a switch statement:

```
    case GET_TRANSACTIONS:
      return {
        ...state,
        transactions: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      };
```

I make the following call in my react component:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getTransactions();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
```

My API is running on a node server that uses a route that first checks for user auth and then queries the database. Again, the API has been tested and returns the data as expected given there is a valid JWT auth token in the headers. The route is below:

```
router.get("/", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const transactions = await Transaction.find({ user: req.user.id }).sort({
      date: -1,
    });
    res.json(transactions);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});
```

I need to be able to have the data returned consistently in my component in an array of objects called transactions so it can be mapped to populate a DOM element. I have tried to provide as much of the code here as I felt was relevant but if I'm missing something, I can share that. All required imports have been doublechecked and are correct. I have not included the import lines in this question to conserve space. Thanks in advance!

Comment: > make any modifications to the code and save
unless you have some kind of state hot reloading then this is always going to happen since things aren't saved anywhere right? your js runs everytime you load the app

Comment: put a console log in your reducer action and make sure it's always passing the right data, I don't see any reason it should be null unless it gets reset like on a page refresh

Comment: Thanks @azium I do have this running the node server and react server with concurrently so there is hot reloading. Shouldn't make a difference though. I have the exact same state configuration for a different module in my app and it work perfectly. Having a hard time finding the issue on this one. Good tip on the reducer. Maybe something is falling through the cracks there